# On $Z (X) = \text{trace}((X^TA_1X)^{-1}X^TA_2X)$

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, quadratic-forms, trace

Is there any way to comment on the quantity,

$$Z (X) = \text{trace}((X^TA_1X)^{-1}X^TA_2X)$$

solely based on $A_1, A_2$?

More clearly, what I mean is, if $A_1 = A_2$, the above quantity is $k$. Can we find out if $Z$ Will be greater or less than $n$,  solely based on some kind of matrix difference between $A_1, A_2$? Like looking at trace of $A_1^{-1}A_2$ Or something on that line. $X$ Is an arbitrary matrix of size $n \times k$. $A_1, A_2$ Both are positive definite.

Comment: Presumably you at least want $X$ to be orthogonal?

Comment: If $A_1=A_2$, isn't the trace equal to $k$ instead ?

Comment: Yes, I will edit that.

Answer (score 1):

### This is only restricted when $A,B,XX^T$ have same eigenvectors

Using SVD, i.e. $X = UDV^T$ where $U,V$ are unitary so
$$Z (X) = \text{trace}((X^TA_1X)^{-1}X^TA_2X) = \text{trace}((VD^TU^TA_1UDV^T)^{-1}VD^TU^TA_2UDV^T) $$
which becomes
$$Z (X) =  \text{trace}((D^TU^TA_1UD)^{-1}D^TU^TA_2UD) $$
Now if $A_1$ and $A_2$ share same eigenvectors $U$ then $A_1 = UD_1U^T$ and $A_2 = UD_2U^T$
$$Z (X) =  \text{trace}((D^TU^T UD_1U^TUD)^{-1}D^TU^T UD_2U^TUD) $$
Since $U$ is unitary, then $UU^T=U^TU=I$
$$Z (X) =  \text{trace}((D^TD_1D)^{-1}D^TD_2D) =\text{trace}((D^TD_1D)^{-1}D^TD_2D) =  \sum\limits_{k=1}^n \frac{\beta_k}{\alpha_k}$$
where $\beta_k$'s are the eigenvalues of $B$ and and $\alpha_k$ are that for $A$. 
Note your case when $A_1=A_2$, then $\alpha_k=\beta_k$ and hence the above adds to $n$.

Comment: That’s a nice derivation. But my $X$ Is completely arbitrary.